# How can i show multi checkbox on datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, if-statement, checkbox

i need show multi checkbox on datagridview.

i have 4 checkbox when select 2 checkbox it's show 2 checkbox on datagridview.

**Ex 2 checkbox.**

**CheckBox missShw**

```
0001
0002
```

**CheckBox leaveFull**

```
0003
0004
```

i'm First select CheckBox missShw and CheckBox leaveFull it's output.

```
0003
0004
```

OR
i'm First select CheckBox leaveFull and CheckBox missShw it's output.

```
0001
0002
```

**i need output when 2 checkbox.**

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

now, i'm select 2 checkbox, so it's show all data to datagridview **but it's don't show all data**.

**This code:**

```
public void missShw() 
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(appConn);
            string sql = "SELECT [filesTA].EmpNo,[Employee].Title + ' ' + [Employee].[First Name] + ' ' + [Employee].[Last Name] as 'FullName',[filesTA].ChkDate"
            + ",Convert(nvarchar(5),[filesTA].ChkIn,108) as 'ChkIn',Convert(nvarchar(5),[filesTA].ChkOut,108) as 'ChkOut"
            + ",[filesTA].LateMin"
            + " From [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] inner join [WebSP].[dbo].[Employee] on [Employee].EmployeeNo=[filesTA].EmpNo INNER JOIN [WebSP].[dbo].[CompanyData] On [CompanyData].Company = [Employee].Company"
            + " WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate ='" + dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
            + " and [Employee].Section = '" + cbSection.SelectedValue + "'"
            + " and [Employee].Team = '" + cbTeam.SelectedValue + "'"
            + " and [filesTA].ErrorCode = '2'";

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Conn.Close();

            dgvShow.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

public void leaveFull()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(appConn);
            string sql = "SELECT [filesTA].EmpNo,[Employee].Title + ' ' + [Employee].[First Name] + ' ' + [Employee].[Last Name] as 'FullName',[filesTA].ChkDate"
            + ",Convert(nvarchar(5),[filesTA].ChkIn,108) as 'ChkIn',Convert(nvarchar(5),[filesTA].ChkOut,108) as 'ChkOut"
            + ",[filesTA].LateMin"
            + " From [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] inner join [WebSP].[dbo].[Employee] on [Employee].EmployeeNo=[filesTA].EmpNo INNER JOIN [WebSP].[dbo].[CompanyData] On [CompanyData].Company = [Employee].Company"
            + " WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate ='" + dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
            + " and [Employee].Section = '" + cbSection.SelectedValue + "'"
            + " and [Employee].Team = '" + cbTeam.SelectedValue + "'"
            + " and [filesTA].ErrorCode = '3'";

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Conn.Close();

            dgvShow.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

//missShw()
        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                missShw();                
            }
        }

//leaveFull()
        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
            {
                leaveFull();                
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: `it's show all data to datagridview but it's don't show all data` my brain threw an exception here. Please clarify your question, maybe include some pictures?

Comment: Ok, i'm edit topic look topic. :)

Comment: I can help you can't help you. :)